# Is there a common lisp macro for popping the nth element from a list?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm pretty fresh to the Common Lisp scene and I can't seem to find an quick way to get the nth element from a list and remove it from said list at the same time. I've done it, but it ain't pretty, what I'd really like is something like "pop" but took a second parameter:

```
(setf x '(a b c d))
(setf y (popnth 2 x))
; x is '(a b d)
; y is 'c
```

I'm pretty sure that "popnth" would have to be a macro, in case the parameter was 0 and it had to behave like "pop".

EDIT: Here's my crap first version:

```
(defmacro popnth (n lst)
  (let ((tempvar (gensym)))
    `(if (eql ,n 0)
      (pop ,lst)
      (let ((,tempvar (nth ,n ,lst)))
        (setf (cdr (nthcdr ,(- n 1) ,lst)) (nthcdr ,(+ n 1) ,lst))
        ,tempvar))))
```

Comment: Why do you call it pop? It would be more clear to call it `remove-at`. Also, there is no need for macro here.

Comment: @leppie : POP is the name chosen by the creators of Common Lisp, not me.

Comment: But it's called pop because you can use the list as a stack data structure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29). You push stuff to a stack and then pop it from the top. You can't pop it from the middle, so actually leppie is right :)

Comment: I'm not the first to give pop an optional position, Python does that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution that is a little more efficient than my first attempt:

```
(defmacro popnth (n lst)
  (let ((t1 (gensym))(t2 (gensym)))
    `(if (eql ,n 0)
      (pop ,lst)
      (let* ((,t1 (nthcdr (- ,n 1) ,lst))
              (,t2 (car (cdr ,t1))))
        (setf (cdr ,t1) (cddr ,t1))
        ,t2))))
```

Here is it in action:

```
[2]> (defparameter *list* '(a b c d e f g))
*LIST*
[3]> (popnth 3 *list*)
D
[4]> *list*
(A B C E F G)
[5]> (popnth 0 *list*)
A
[6]> *list*
(B C E F G)
```

Answer (score 11):

Something like this:

**Removing the nth element of a list**:

```
(defun remove-nth (list n)
  (remove-if (constantly t) list :start n :end (1+ n)))
```

[constantly](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cons_1.htm) returns a function, that always returns its argument.

**As a macro that accepts a [place](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#place), using [define-modify-macro](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_2.htm)**:

```
(define-modify-macro remove-nth-f (n) remove-nth "Remove the nth element")
```

**POP-NTH**

```
(defmacro pop-nth (list n)
  (let ((n-var (gensym)))
    `(let ((,n-var ,n))
       (prog1 (nth ,n-var ,list)
         (remove-nth-f ,list ,n-var)))))
```

**Example**:

```
CL-USER 26 > (defparameter *list* (list 1 2 3 4))
*LIST*

CL-USER 27 > (pop-nth *list* 0)
1

CL-USER 28 > *list*
(2 3 4)

CL-USER 29 > (pop-nth *list* 2)
4

CL-USER 30 > *list*
(2 3)
```

Comment: I'm no lisp guru, but isn't the macro wrong because 1) evaluates n first, 2) evaluates list twice (once for nth and once for the updating macro) ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Lisp has a macro for popping the N-th element of a list: it is called `pop`.

```
$ clisp -q
[1]> (defvar list (list 0 1 2 3 4 5))
LIST
[2]> (pop (cdddr list))
3
[3]> list
(0 1 2 4 5)
[4]>
```

`pop` works with any form that denotes a place.

The problem is that, unlike `cddr`, `nthcdr` isn't an accessor; a form like `(nthcdr 3 list)` does not denote a place; it works only as a function call.

Writing a specialized form of `pop` is not the best answer; rather, we can achieve a more general fix by writing a clone of `nthcdr` which behaves like a place accessor. Then the `pop` macro will work, and **so will every other macro** that works with places like `setf` and `rotatef`.

```
;; our clone of nthcdr called cdnth
(defun cdnth (idx list)
  (nthcdr idx list))

;; support for (cdnth <idx> <list>) as an assignable place
(define-setf-expander cdnth (idx list &environment env)
   (multiple-value-bind (dummies vals newval setter getter)
                        (get-setf-expansion list env)
     (let ((store (gensym))
           (idx-temp (gensym)))
       (values dummies
               vals
               `(,store)
               `(let ((,idx-temp ,idx))
                  (progn
                    (if (zerop ,idx-temp)
                      (progn (setf ,getter ,store))
                      (progn (rplacd (nthcdr (1- ,idx-temp) ,getter) ,store)))
                    ,store))
               `(nthcdr ,idx ,getter)))))
```

Test:

```
$ clisp -q -i cdnth.lisp 
;; Loading file cdnth.lisp ...
;; Loaded file cdnth.lisp
[1]> (defvar list (list 0 1 2 3 4 5))
LIST
[2]> (pop (cdnth 2 list))
2
[3]> list
(0 1 3 4 5)
[4]> (pop (cdnth 0 list))
0
[5]> list
(1 3 4 5)
[6]> (pop (cdnth 3 list))
5
[7]> list
(1 3 4)
[8]> (pop (cdnth 1 list))
3
[9]> list
(1 4)
[10]> (pop (cdnth 1 list))
4
[11]> list
(1)
[12]> (pop (cdnth 0 list))
1
[13]> list
NIL
[14]>
```

A possible improvement to the implementation is to analyze the `idx` form and optimize away the generated code that implements the run-time check on the value of `idx`. That is to say, if `idx` is a constant expression, there is no need to emit the code which tests whether `idx` is zero. The appropriate code variant can just be emitted.  Not only that, but for small values of `idx`, the code can emit special variants based on the "cadavers": `cddr`, `cdddr`, rather than the general `nthcdr`. However, some of these optimizations might be done by the Lisp compiler and thus redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I have same suspicion as @6502...If I remember right...Neither `push` nor `pop` can be defined as modify-macros, the former because the `place` is not its first argument, and the latter because its return value is not the modified object.

#### Definition of `define-modify-macro`

An expression of the form `(define-modify-macro m (p1 ... pn) f)` defines a new macro `m`, such that a call of the form `(m place a1 ... an)` will cause `place` to be set to `(f val a1 ... an)`, where `val` represents the value of `place`. The parameters may also include rest and optional parameters. The string, if present, becomes the documentation of the new macro.

I have this `popnth` works just fine:

```
(defun nthpop (index lst)
  (pop (nthcdr (1- index) lst)))

> *list*
(1 2 3 4 5)
> (nthpop 2 *list*)
2
> *list*
(1 3 4 5)
```