# Function that is always evaluated to t (or any value)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, predicate

Say, we would like to use a function that requires a predicate, but for some reason we're interested in other features of the function (like `:start` and `:end` parameters), so we need to supply a predicate, that always returns true.

Obviously, it's not a problem at all:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *list* '(0 1 2 3 4 5))
*LIST*
CL-USER> (remove-if (lambda (x) t) *list* :start 1 :end 3)
(0 3 4 5)
```

Works, but not beautifully at all. And we may get ugly message that variable `x` is not used. Since I'm in LISP for beauty, I'm curious if there is a 'always t' predicate?

We can define it:

```
(defun tp (&rest rest)
  (declare (ignore rest))
  t)
```

..but may be it exists?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for the function [`constantly`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cons_1.htm) that takes an argument and returns a function that always returns that value.  The predicate you need, then is `(constantly t)`. Thus:

```
CL-USER> (remove-if (constantly t) '(0 1 2 3 4 5) :start 1 :end 3)
(0 3 4 5)
```

The notes on `constantly` show that you were absolutely on the right track with your proposed implementation.  (You did even better, though, by adding the `(declare (ignore …))`.)

> #### Notes:
>
> constantly could be defined by:
>
> ```
> (defun constantly (object)
>   #'(lambda (&rest arguments) object))
> ```

---

After writing this, it occurred to me that this might be a duplicate.  I didn't find a proper duplicate, found a similar, more specific, question that was looking to remove a single element at a position, [Is there a common lisp macro for popping the nth element from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4093845/1281433), in which [Rainer Joswig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094071/1281433) includes:

> #### Removing the nth element of a list:
>
> ```
> (defun remove-nth (list n)
>   (remove-if (constantly t) list :start n :end (1+ n)))
> ```

This is really just a generalization of that approach, since you're working with arbitrary sequence boundaries.  Thus we could have (making the boundary argument analogous to `subseq`'s):

```
(defun remove-subseq (sequence &optional (start 0) end)
  (remove-if (constantly t) sequence :start start :end end))

(defun remove-nth (sequence n)
  (remove-subseq sequence n (1+ n)))
```

```
CL-USER> (remove-subseq '(0 1 2 3 4 5) 1 3)
(0 3 4 5)
CL-USER> (remove-nth '(0 1 2 3 4 5) 3)
(0 1 2 4 5)
```

Comment: What a useful function ;-) Thanks!